# Problema con un biestable JK

Tags: c++, c

Llevo desde hace un tiempo, intentando simular en C++ todos los biestables / latch /flip flop's. Hasta ahora no me ha ido mal, pero aquí he tropezado y no se como puedo hacer para solucionarlo.

Un biestable es un dispositivo que almacena un bit de información. Se crean agrupando puertas lógicas de una manera concreta. La teoría la se pero no entiendo donde está el fallo. Muestro el codigo:

```
void JKupdate(bool J, bool K, bool ck)
    {
    
        jkS_ = Gates.AND3(J,ck,jknQ_);
        jkR_ = Gates.AND3(K,ck,jkQ_);
        
        jkQ_ = Gates.NOR(jkR_,jknQ_);
        jknQ_ = Gates.NOR(jkS_,jkQ_);
        j_ = J;
        k_ = K;
        ck_ = ck;
        JKstatus();
    }
    void JKstatus()
    {
        printf("Status JK Latch: \n");
        printf("J = %d, K = %d, CK = %d \n", j_,k_,ck_);
        printf("Q = %d \n",jkQ_);
    }
```

Las funciones 'Gates.AND3(J,ck,jknQ_)' y 'Gates.NOR(jkR_,jknQ_)' están en un struct que devuelven la operación lógica hecha con las entradas de estas.

Explico en un tabla el funcionamiento, para que se entienda donde está el fallo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ck, que representa los pulsos del reloj, está en cero. El biestable devuelve el valor Q. Ahora, si Ck es 1, debe de realizar lo que indica la tabla. Siendo !Q la inversa de lo que haya.

Pues ese caso es justo el problematico. Yo introduzco esto:

```
int main()
{
    bool ck = 1;
    Latch.JKstatus();
    //Establezco un valor para el Latch
    Latch.JKupdate(0,1,ck);
    //Voy cambiando dicho valor
    Latch.JKupdate(1,1,ck);
    Latch.JKupdate(1,1,ck);
    Latch.JKupdate(1,1,ck);
    Latch.JKupdate(1,1,ck);
    Latch.JKupdate(1,1,ck);
    Latch.JKupdate(1,1,ck);
    Latch.JKupdate(1,1,ck);

    return 0;

}
```

La respuesta es que devuelve el valor de 0 dos veces. Cuando debería de cambiar, de 0 a 1 y viceversa. Comparto la salida:

```
Status JK Latch: 
J = 0, K = 0, CK = 0 
Q = 0 
Status JK Latch: 
J = 0, K = 1, CK = 1 
Q = 1 
Status JK Latch: 
J = 1, K = 1, CK = 1 
Q = 0 
Status JK Latch: 
J = 1, K = 1, CK = 1 
Q = 0 
Status JK Latch: 
J = 1, K = 1, CK = 1 
Q = 1 
Status JK Latch: 
J = 1, K = 1, CK = 1 
Q = 0 
Status JK Latch: 
J = 1, K = 1, CK = 1 
Q = 0 
Status JK Latch: 
J = 1, K = 1, CK = 1 
Q = 1 
Status JK Latch: 
J = 1, K = 1, CK = 1 
Q = 0
```

La primera es el valor originario. No entiendo donde puede estar el fallo y por eso pido ayuda. Muchas gracias.